# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n= 1.$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n= 1.$

I need to show that there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}: \forall n \geq N : \left|(1-\frac{1}{n^2})^n-1\right| \lt \epsilon$ $,\:\:\forall \epsilon \gt 0.$

Since $(1-\frac{1}{n^2})^n \leq 1$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_+ \Rightarrow \left|(1-\frac{1}{n^2})^n-1\right| = 1 - (1-\frac{1}{n^2})^n$

Therefore I need to solve $1 - \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n < \epsilon$ for $n$.

Unfortunately I cannot solve this explicitly for n. The best I can do is:

$$\log(1-\epsilon) \lt n \log\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Is there a way to solve this for $n$ explicitly? How can I prove this if this is if it is not solvable for $n$?

Comment: Do you know that $(1 + 1/n)^n \rightarrow e$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the expansion of $(1-\frac{1}{n^2})^n.$

$$\begin{align}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n &= 1 - n\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}\dfrac{1}{n^4} - \cdots \\ &= 1-\dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{n-1}{2n^3}+\cdots\\&\geq1-\dfrac{1}{n}\end{align}$$

We can construct the inequality $$1-\dfrac{1}{n} \leq \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n \leq 1$$

Subtract $1$ and then change the order of inequality

$$-\dfrac{1}{n} \leq \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n -1 \leq 0$$

$$0 \leq 1- \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n \leq \dfrac{1}{n}$$

After this you can just choose $N = \left\lceil\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}\right\rceil.$

Comment: I am not sure that the expansion you use and the way you use it are enough to prove the inequality $(1-1/{n^2})^n\geqslant1-1/n$ (which holds nevertheless). You might want to make this point more precise.

Comment: @Did I will amend my post to make the inequality more clear. On a related note, would it be an issue to expand around $n = \infty$?

Comment: @user147887 It seems that you want to show that all the remaining terms of the series sum to something above 0. That is $\frac{1}{2 n^2}-\frac{2}{3 n^3}\ge 0$, $\frac{13}{24 n^4}-\frac{71}{120 n^5}\ge 0$, $\frac{391}{720 n^6}-\frac{709}{1260 n^7}\ge0$, ... However presumably this requires some argument.

Answer (score 10):

**Hint:** if $x\geqslant 0$ and $n$ is an integer, then $(1-x)^n\geqslant 1-nx$.

This can be seen definigin $f(x)=(1-x)^n+nx$ and showing that the derivative is non-negative.

Answer (score 8):

Hint:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{\Large n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{\Large n^2}\right]^{\Large\frac{1}{n}},
\end{equation}
where $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{\Large n^2}=\frac {1}{e}$.

Comment: Thanks Mr. @Eleven-Eleven. No one but you notice it, luckily I didn't get downvote \\(^◡^)/

Comment: Did you downvote my answer Mr. @Eleven-Eleven?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I'm not convinced.  Why are you allowed to take the limit of the expression in square brackets first, before taking the limit including the power $1/n$?

Comment: @SpamIAm
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{ n^2}\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}=\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}\right]^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}}
$$

Comment: Actually it is formalised using the 'product rule' $\lim fg=\lim f\lim g$ with $f=\frac1n$ and $g=\ln((1-n^{-2})^{n^2})$, and continuity of $\ln$ and $\exp$.

Comment: @barto It's valid to move the limit as long as the function is continuous. See this [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Other_indeterminate_forms).

Comment: Heuristically,
$\left(\,1 - {1 \over n^{2}}\,\right)^{n} = \exp\left(\,n\ln\left(\,1 - {1 \over n^{2}}\,\right)\,\right) \sim\exp\left(\,-\,{1 \over n}\,\right)$ when $n \gg 1$.